# Converting word document to Python-docx module

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

I want to create a word document using the `python-docx` module.

I'm seeing from the official documentation syntaxes like this:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

document = Document()

document.add_heading('Document Title', 0)

p = document.add_paragraph('A plain paragraph having some ')
p.add_run('bold').bold = True
p.add_run(' and some ')
p.add_run('italic.').italic = True

document.add_heading('Heading, level 1', level=1)
document.add_paragraph('Intense quote', style='Intense Quote')

document.add_paragraph(
    'first item in unordered list', style='List Bullet'
)

document.add_picture('monty-truth.png', width=Inches(1.25))
```

Now, is there a way to convert an **existing Word document** into these related `python-docx` syntaxes so I can work on exactly what I want from the MS-Word GUI, get the docx file and then converting to the `python-docx` syntaxes so I can just edit the texts within the formatted syntaxes when I use it in my python app?

Random google searches haven't answered me and I was wondering if someone here has done this before, thank you.

Comment: I am unsure what you exactly mean. Do you just want to open an existing .docx file? In this case the [documentation](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/documents.html) is complete. Just use `document = Document('existing-document-file.docx')`.

Comment: Okay, This helps. Not just sure how I can now access the `python-docx` syntaxes to edit the document I opened. After opening the existing document, how do I proceed to edit the document with from `python-docx`? Cos the whole point is using the template I opened and filling it with new content from the results of the python app I'm creating.

Comment: Parsing Word documents with Python  https://dadoverflow.com/2022/01/30/parsing-word-documents-with-python/

Comment: or using docx https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50506553/parsing-docx-files-in-python